# How to queue cookies in lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, lumen

I am trying to queue various cookies in response in Lumen.

I've added `\Illuminate\Cookie\` into my Composer.

I added Following code in `app.php`

```
$app->singleton('cookie', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'cookie');
});

$app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Cookie\QueueingFactory', 'cookie');
```

In My Controller, I am trying the following code

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('test', 'tada', 10, '/'));
//Few more business logic here: before returning the response
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response('exit');
return $response->withHeaders($headers);
```

I can see my queued cookies using `Cookie::getQueuedCookies()`

but still, after a response, my cookie is nowhere to be found.
I tried various answers from StackOverflow questions but still couldn't resolve it

I can't use `response()->withCookie()` solution because I am creating cookies at various points of my code, and can't pull them together at the time of response

Answer (score 0):

Queued cookies in Laravel are handled by the `\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` class.

It begs the question why you'd use Lumen if you wanted cookies support but you should be able to add this middleware to your HTTP stack in Lumen.

Comment: Hi Devon, Can you please explain your answer -  How can I use this class for my purpose?

Comment: The easier thing is just to use Laravel if you want cookies.  Lumen is a micro-framework for APIs, cookies don't really belong which is why they aren't included.  The small performance benefit you'd get from Lumen won't justify your mis-use of it.

Comment: I completely understand your point. but sometimes you don't have any control over techs that are already being used.

Comment: Laravel is a drop-in replacement for Lumen, so it really shouldn't be an issue.  Adding middleware to Lumen should be fairly well documented if you choose not to do it that way.

Comment: Here's an answer to why someone might do it: what if the cookies are only needed a single time -- for handling an OAuth flow? That's the case for my application. JWT is used everywhere else, but the cookie is used to set up the access/refresh token.

Comment: @AustinBurk I still wouldn't recommend using cookies for that purpose.   As the API layer and oauth server, you should dictate how the client refreshes their token.